# CSS target text input fields by order

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a html form with the following text input fields. No class, no id, same type.

I need to style them in a different way.

Is it possible to target them by order using pure CSS?

Something like:

CSS (not working)

```css
input[0] {
  height: 100px;
}

input[1] {
  height: 150px;
}

input[2] {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input name="arr[]" type="text">
<input name="arr[]" type="text">
<input name="arr[]" type="text">
```

I know that I could use *:nth-child* or *:nth-of-type*, but I wonder if there's another way to target those elements, like in my CSS example.

Thanks.

Comment: `input:nth-child(1)` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It works with :nth-of-type, instead. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try :nth-child, like this:

```
input:nth-child(1) {
  height: 100px;
}
input:nth-child(2) {
  height: 150px;
}
input:nth-child(3) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It works with :nth-of-type, instead. Thanks anyway.